# Was any reviewer critical of the depiction of ape behavior when the films came out?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes

I believe Planet of the Apes and sequels basically have chimps as the intellectual and more compassionate species while gorillas are shown as militaristic. It is possible that in the 1960s and early 1970s very little was known of both chimp and gorilla behavior -- it may not have been known that chimps hunted and ate meat while I believe even today there is no evidence of gorilla being anything but vegetarians.

I realize that science fiction often plays fast and loose with actual science but the films actually seem to me to have been the result of some input from experts on ape behavior as it was then understood.

Comment: Typical anti-gorilla propaganda.

Comment: Of course, all the non-human Apes we see have been 'uplifted', so who's to say the process didn't alter their personalities?

Comment: Planet of the Apes was fast and loosely based on a book for starters...

Comment: The vision of gorillas as compassionate, calm and familiar herbivores is from the early eighties and the success of Diane Fossey's book "Gorillas in the Mist". The sixties and seventies were the time of movies like Kaijus such as "King Kong vs. Godzilla" or "King Kong" by Dino de Laurentis, where the gorilla is seen as a pure warrior, that can be noble but very aggressive.

Comment: I understand that the Gibbons were really pissed, but nobody cared.

Comment: Is your question about what reviewers said, or about how much scientific input the script had?

Answer (score 5):

Jane Goodall began closely observing chimpanzees in 1960, and Diane Fossey began closly observing gorillas in 1966.

Goodall's discovery of chimps using and making tools was a scientific sensation in the early 1960s.  Anyone with a scientific interest would have heard about it. But apparently it took her some more years to discover chimpanzee violence.

Pierre Boulle published the novel *La planete des singes* in 1963, translated as *Planet of the Apes* in 1963.  Movie rights are purchsed before publication and Rod Serling wrote a script, which was largely rewritten by Michael Wilson in the years before production began.  And some scenes were improvised during filming.

[*The Planet of the Apes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes_(1968_film)#Filming) (1968) was filmed from May 21 to August 10, 1967.

[*Battle for the Planet of the Apes*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069768/locations?ref_=ttrel_sa_4) (1973) has a filming date of 3 January 1973, either the beginning or the ending of its filming.

The other films in the series were filmed between those dates.

And scripts are sometimes rewritten during filming.  So if the creators of those movies were aware of ongoing primate research and felt a desire to depict chimp or gorilla behavior more accurately, they could have changed some scenes in to be more accurate.  But apparently they didn't consider that important.

And I imagine that most movie reviewers in 1967 to 1973 were not very much  aware of Jane Goodall's discoveries or Diane Fossey's.

But I am not familiar with the reviews of the ape films.

Comment: I would further say that the popular perception at the time was that gorillas were the "tougher" ape, based on their size, and that perception would take a long time to catch up to the science, if in fact it has even now, which is debatable.  The filmmakers would have crafted their story with that perception in mind.

Comment: @tbrookside: I will say, if you had no idea of what a gorilla was and that they are basically gentle (most of the time) and intelligent creatures. encountering one, with its size and very scary dentition, would be very much seeing a real werewolf. Chimps also would be scary but significantly less so although they are in fact the more dangerous species.